# replacing .php ext with .html through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Greetings!

I'm trying to replace .php extensions with .html

So far I got:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php
```

... it works nicely when url like `/site/page.html` is entered (and `page.html` does not physically exist but `page.php` does).

However what I'd like to have is when `/site/page.php` is entered the viewer sees only `/site/page.html` in the browser location.

Is that doable or do I have to set up explicit redirects for each page? :-(

Thanks in advance.

ps: dev environment I'm using is XAMPP on os x if it makes any difference

Comment: If you are going that far why even have an extension at all? just have /site/page reference the .php page.  It looks cleaner.

Comment: You can check out this tutorial on how to replace `.php` with `.html` using htaccess https://helponnet.com/2021/04/27/how-to-convert-php-extension-into-html-using-rewriterule-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php
```

*edit after pulling white rabbit out of the hat*

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```

Comment: ... something's wrong, when I enter "http://localhost/site/index.php" I get "http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/index.html", not sure what to make of it

Comment: this puts my Apache into endless loop

Comment: ... rewrite base didn't help :-(

Comment: ... that did it! Except for the peculiarity of dealing with XAMPP, for rewrie base I have to use '/site/' instead of just the '/' That's what happens when I don't work with the stuff on regular basis :-) Thanks

Comment: just nee to remove this line *RewriteBase /*

Comment: after apply this solution .php pages are working fine as .html but existing .html page are stopped working.. could you please help for what to do for existing .html files?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```

Comment: after apply this solution .php pages are working fine as .html but existing .html page are stopped working.. could you please help for what to do for existing .html files?

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that this is much simple

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

it just process every .html file as normal .php

if you want it only for current dir

```
<Files *.html>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```