# How to change .php extension of website pages?

Tags: php, url, browser

I have a website running on PHP. I want to remove the `.php` suffix from all of my webpages in such way that the user doesn't get to know what server side language is running.

How do I edit the displayed address in the address bar to not show the `.php` ?

Comment: probably you are looking for mod_rewrite .htaccess

Comment: possible duplicate of [replacing .php ext with .html through .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548860/replacing-php-ext-with-html-through-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache has a feature, 'MultiViews' that allows the server to choose the correct extension when none is supplied. In your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`, you can add this:

```
Options MultiViews
```

If you have a file at `/path/to/blah.php`, it can be accessed as merely `/path/to/blah`.