# Change .php to .html through htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a program that provide step registration1,step registration2. My structure like this:

```
localhost/bandung/registration.php
```

then when submit button, the page will send parameter

```
localhost/bandung/registration.php?user=xxxxxx
```

Can I change the extention of php to html but still have the parameter like:

```
localhost/bandung/registration.html?user=xxxxxx
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548860/replacing-php-ext-with-html-through-htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replacing .php ext with .html through .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548860/replacing-php-ext-with-html-through-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Create in your `bandung` folder a new htaccess file. Then add the following lines in it:

```
# Set Rewrite Engine on
RewriteEngine on

# Create rewrite rule for your registration.php
RewriteRule ^registration.html?user=(.*)$ registration.php?user=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php
```

edit after pulling white rabbit out of the hat

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```